# Is it possible to access dag_run.conf from a SubDag?

Tags: airflow

It looks like you can access a dag_run's conf parameters using the `PythonOperator` and setting `provide_context=true` or by using jinja templating + the `BashOperator`. Is there a built in way to provide access to these values to the `SubDagOperator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AIRFLOW/issues/AIRFLOW-2355?filter=allopenissues&orderby=priority%20ASC%2C%20updated%20DESC) seems to imply that it is currently not possible to pass conf parameters from a parent DAG to a subdag.

Answer (score 0):

I decided not to trust the accepted answer and found out how to do this.

The reason you can't access the dag_run.conf of the DAG is because each subdag has its own dag_run.conf that is separate from the parent and that will be None unless a conf argument is set on the SubDagOperator. Passing this conf argument into SubDagOperator still doesn't help however as you can't template on that parameter to get access to the parent dag's dag_run.conf.

If you want to access the dag_run.conf of the parent, what you can do instead is get a handle to the parent dag from your dag object (or as a template expression) and call get_dagrun() on it to get access to the parents dag_run.conf configuration.

See example:

```
def run_this_func(dag, execution_date, **kwargs):
    parent_dag_run = dag.parent_dag.get_dagrun(execution_date)
    print(dag.parent_dag.get_dagrun(execution_date).conf['YOUR_KEY_HERE'])

PythonOperator(
    task_id=f"run_this_func",
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=run_this_func,
    dag=dag,
)
```